# GORM model split over two tables with embedded struct

Tags: sql, go, orm, grails-orm, go-gorm

I have a schema like so:

`entityA <1-2-1> entityB <1-2-MANY> entityC`

modelled like this:

```
type EntityA struct {
 ID uuid.UUID `gorm:"column:id"`
 *EntityB
}

type EntityB struct {
  EntCs []*EntityC `gorm:"foreignKey:entity_b_id;references:id"`
}

type EntityC struct {
  EntityBID uuid.UUID `gorm:"column:entity_b_id"`
}
```

I want to execute a query, using GORM, that will select EntityA with EntityB fields populated and preload EntityC.

Selecting EntityA with EntityB fields populated can be achieved using the `join` method but it fails to preload EntityC and I suspect the reason is because GORM doesn't not understand the association between `entityA` and `entityB` tables and so can not make the association between EntityA and EntityC.

Is there a way to annotate or via some other means make GORM aware of the underlying schema such that it can execute the preload of EntityC?

Answer (score -1):

I have an example code like your relations. And it works fine.
`User <1-n> Post <1-n> Comment`
You need to ensure that two adjacent structures have fields to associate. I didn't see `primaryKey` and `EntityAID` in `EntityB`.

In addition to the respective primary key, `Post` should have `UserID`, `Comment` should have `PostID`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "os"
)

type User struct {
    ID    uint   `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Posts []Post `gorm:"foreignKey:user_id;references:id"`
}

type Post struct {
    ID       uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    UserId   uint64
    Comments []Comment `gorm:"foreignKey:post_id;references:id"`
}

type Comment struct {
    ID     uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    PostID uint
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("blog.db"), &gorm.Config{
        DisableForeignKeyConstraintWhenMigrating: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove("blog.db")
    if err := db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Post{}, &Comment{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.Create(&User{Posts: []Post{{Comments: []Comment{{}, {}, {}}}}})
    db.Create(&User{Posts: []Post{{}, {}}})

    var out []*User
    db.Model(&User{}).Preload("Posts").Preload("Posts.Comments").Find(&out)
    b, _ := json.Marshal(&out)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Posts": [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "UserId": 1,
        "Comments": [
          {
            "ID": 1,
            "PostID": 1
          },
          {
            "ID": 2,
            "PostID": 1
          },
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "PostID": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Posts": [
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "UserId": 2,
        "Comments": []
      },
      {
        "ID": 3,
        "UserId": 2,
        "Comments": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: you have two 1-2-n relations, I have 1-2-1 and 1-2-n